# eclipse complains getSystemCpuLoad method not available in OperatingSystemMXBean in Java 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, jmx

I have configured my `Eclipse` to use `JRE 8`. I confirmed it in `buildPath`.

The `compiler` is specified as `1.8`.

I am trying to get the [`SystemCpuLoad`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad--). Here is what I have.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;

    OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

    operatingSystemBean.getSystemCpuLoad();
```

Eclipse complains saying "no getSystemCpuLoad()" method.
I thought it could be an `eclipse` issue and try using `maven`.
still build fails with the following error.

```
java:[221,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getSystemCpuLoad()
[ERROR] location: variable operatingSystemBean of type java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean
```

I am unable to figure what is going wrong?

**EDIT**:

In the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) it says 
`Platform-specific management interface for the operating system on which the Java virtual machine is running.`

which means some methods are available in one OS than others.
but how can I handle it during compile time to run in linux or mac?

I am currently using mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to

ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

returns an instance of java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean

To access the com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean functionality you will need to cast to com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.

Comment: yes, I figured that out. but for some reasons, I unable to import sun package although it is in JRE library. please see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619229/unable-to-import-org-sun-management-operatingsystemmxbean-in-java-class