# unable to import org.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean in java class?

Tags: java, java-8, sun

I see the `org.sun.management` in JRE System library but I am unable to import in my eclipse. Any reasons why it is allowed. even maven compilation fails

here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I am using `Java 8.`

I am trying to do this:

```
if (operatingSystemBean  instanceof com.sun.mananagement.OperatingSystemMXBean) {


        })
```

Answer (score 9):

Eclipse is preventing you from accessing Sun's proprietary implementation details as that won't be portable across other JVMs.

You can change the project settings so that Eclipse will treat that type of issue as a warning rather than as an error.

My steps for Latest Eclipse on Mac:

Project - Properties
    -> Java Compiler
        -> Errors / Warnings
            -> Enable Project specific settings
                -> Deprecated and restricted API
                    -> Forbidden reference : Warning

Comment: It is not deprecated error. It is compilation error. even Maven compilation fails (not using eclipse)

Comment: My Eclipse setup showed the problem as "Access restriction: The type 'OperatingSystemMXBean' is not API (restriction on required library '..../jre/lib/rt.jar'"

Comment: I've created a pom.xml for my toy project that includes the relevant import and maven compilation succeeded.  What does mvn -version output for you?

Comment: `Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T13:10:27-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.1
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"`

Comment: My Maven setup looks quite similar, so not sure whether that is significant, but anyway.       Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T12:57:37+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: As far as I know, Maven uses the Eclipse compiler, so that’s perfectly in line. Besides that, it makes a difference how you configure your build path. When you point to an “Execution Environment”, it bears the information about the official API, when you just point to a JRE library, all `public` classes are available…

Answer (score -1):

I've just noticed a typo in the instanceof check in your code

mananagement - should be management